# Python Regex - Escaping

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python regex that takes a string (database connection URI) and splits it using named groups into username, password etc.

```
uri = 'username:password@host/database'
m = re.compile('^(?P<user>[^:@]+)(\:(?P<password>[^@]*))?@(?P<host>[^\:@/]+)(\:(?P<port>[0-9]+))?/(?P<db>[^\?]+)?$').match(uri)
print m.groupdict()
{'host': 'host', 'password': 'password', 'db': 'database', 'user': 'username', 'port': None}
```

This works fine. The problem is if the uri has a @ symbol in it, since that's used to split password and host. For example,

```
uri = 'username:p@ssword@host/database'
```

will not match, which is expected. However, I'd like to be able to escape the special character, eg:

```
uri = 'username:p\@ssword@host/database'
```

and have it match. My regex experience is pretty limited - I guess what I'd like to do is modify the

```
(?P<password>[^@]*)
```

group so that it will match any character that's not a @, unless it's preceded by a \ character. Of course, some (most) connection strings will not contain a \@ at all.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why is it not URL-encoded in the first place?

Comment: Not sure, it's not my code originally. It's actually from web2py. Anyway, wouldn't I have the same problem if it was URL encoded, ie the @'s were replaced with %40's? They'd still need escaping..

Comment: No, since the regex engine doesn't URL-decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take is you want greedy matching, that is password is up the last @ and hostname is between last @ and first /

A simple way could be like this:

```
In [68]: re.match('((?P<user>.*):)((?P<pass>.*)@)((?P<host>.*)/)((?P<db>.*))', "username:p@ssword@host/data").groupdict()
Out[68]: {'db': 'data', 'host': 'host', 'pass': 'p@ssword', 'user': 'username'}
```

You might want to add optionals, that is (stuff)+ if e.g. username and password can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for that. Good answers all around, but this is exactly what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
(?P<password>([^\\@]|\\.)*)
```

This scans through your string and matches either: a non-`\` or non-`@`, OR a backslash in which case it matches whatever follows too. The only way an '@' can be matched by that regex is if it sneaks in through the `\\.` regex, ie it's escaped.

As an aside, to write regex in python, use r"insert_regex_here".

Otherwise for a regex `\\.`, you have to write it in python like `"\\\\."`. TO avoid that you can do `r"\\."`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `re.split`:

```
>>> print re.split(r"(?<!\\)@|/|:", r"username:password@host/database")
['username', 'password', 'host', 'database']
>>> print re.split(r"(?<!\\)@|/|:", r"username:p\@ssword@host/database")
['username', 'p\\@ssword', 'host', 'database']
```